# How to change the default hue for red color in an Image?

Tags: iphone

In My App I need to change a dress color , i am using a colorpicker to do it.For a red color shirt  i need to apply  the color,its not exactly working and appearing with a dark shade.Can we change the hue for red color compatible to the picker color? here is my code

```
    imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    NSLog(@"imageLayer %@",imageLayer);
    NSLog(@"self.layer %@",self.layer);
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 660, 1000);
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    imageLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    //imageLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"].CGImage;
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];
    subLayer = [CALayer layer];
    subLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 660, 1000);
    subLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    subLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    subLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"].CGImage;
    [imageLayer addSublayer:subLayer];
```

Comment: found solution? i'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

see this sample, it will help you
https://github.com/RSully/RSColorPicker/

Comment: ya, I have this picker,but I was unable show the same color(Picked color) on the red color shirt in the app..its appearing with some what dark Shade to the choosen color..